# find files in clearcase

Tags: clearcase

situation:
one vob, 2 views (main dev and branch view).

i need to find all files that where created in the branch view and therefore can't be found via merge manager.

anyone able to help?

thanks

Comment: sorry about the `brtype_sub`: I meant `brtype`. And it does list *precisely* all files in the branch view that are not existent in the main view.

Comment: If you have any error message, or any file you feel this request should not find, complete your question and leave a comment on my answer: I will investigate.

Answer (score 6):

When it comes to cleartool find, the two sources of information and example I recommend are:

- [SAMECS find command](http://www.samecs.com/commands/cleartool%20commands/find/find.htm)
- [IBM find examples](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rcss=faqtt_1Q09&uid=swg21124425)

In your case:

```
cleartool find -all -ele "brtype(mybranch) && !brtype(main)" -print
```

(supposing "main dev" means "branch 'main'")

```
cleartool find -all -type f -ele "brtype(mybranch) && !brtype(main)" -print
```

would limit that to files only (not directories)

Comment: To be executed anywhere within your (snapshot or dynamic) view

Comment: many thanks for your realy quick answer. 
i'll take a close look at the links you wrote.
To my problem: i think its not the solution, because i do need all files in the branch view that are not existent in the main view. Also brtype_sub is not a recognized operator (error). We are using CC 7.0.0 ...

The files i like to get are the once created in the branch view, not in the main view, and then brached to the brach view.