# How to search files by label

Tags: clearcase

As title, I'd like to list all the files with a given label under a directory. Which clearcase command can help me to do that ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[cleartool find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311623/find-files-in-clearcase/1311665#1311665) is a good start.

You can execute those anywhere within your (snapshot or dynamic) view

> To generate the list of those elements which contain a version with a predetermined label (REL1) attached, use the following syntax of the cleartool find command:

UNIX and Linux:

```
% cleartool find -all -element '{lbtype_sub(REL1)}' -print
```

Windows:

```
cleartool find -all -element "{lbtype_sub(REL1)}" -print
```

Answer (score 2):

There is also a graphical way to find objects with a certain label called Report Builder (also known in ClearCase Explorer as Report Wizard).  In Report Builder you can navigate to Elements/Labels which has the "Elements with Labels" and "Versions with Labels" reports. After the report runs you have the option to save the results as HTML, XML, or CSV.