# Find changes between labels

Tags: clearcase

Using cleartool I am able to find all the files associated with a label using something like:

```
ct find -avobs -version "lbtype (Build-Label)" -print
```

How do I find all objects changed (including adds and deletes) between two labels?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In ClearCase (under Administration in my install) there is Report Builder.  Under Elements/Labels you can select either "Elements Changed Between Two Labels" or "Versions Changed Between Two Labels" depending on which you need.  You can then select the path to analyze and select the two labels to compare.

After the process runs you have the option to save the results as HTML, XML, or CSV.

Comment: I am able to see the change list between two labels using Cleacase Report Builder. Now, How can I find the number of lines added/modified/deleted between two Labels? Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6):

There is a another way to do it , where `LABEL1` is the old label and `LABEL2` is the latest. Check the date of creation of the labels and swap them before issuing the command as it prints the negation of the `&&` conditional statement. Works like magic!

[image]

```
$(cleartool find $PWD -ver "!lbtype($LABEL1) && lbtype($LABEL2)" -print)
```

Comment: I haven't tested it yet, but it looks interesting. +1

Comment: I have used a similar form: `cleartool find . -type f -nxname -version "version(\main\LATEST) && !lbtype(LABEL_27_12_2016)" -print`

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the answer to "[How to search files by label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220622/how-to-search-files-by-label/2221254#2221254)"

```
cleartool find -all -element "{lbtype_sub(REL1)}" -print
```

is simpler and `lbtype_sub` allow the query to be true if any version of the element has the label
(see [`query_language` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/query_language.htm))

```
cleartool find -all -element '{lbtype_sub(REL1) && lbtype_sub(REL2)}' ^ 
  -version '{!(lbtype(REL1) && lbtype(REL2)) && ^
  (lbtype(REL2) || lbtype(REL1))}' -print
```

would find all elements that do not have both labels, listing all versions in the current VOB labeled either REL1 or REL2 but not both.

Note: if the label is a UCM baseline, this is off course even simpler ([`ct diffbl`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_diffbl.htm)):

```
ct diffbl -ver BL1@\myPVob BL2@\myPVob
```

Answer (score 0):

To find all elements, also those deleted or not selected by your config_spec, add `–nvisible` to the find options.

For comparision I have a shell script called `freeze-list` which more or less runs the same find command as you have there (redirecting the output to `<label>.versions`).

I then have some other perl scripts which takes two such files, reads them and compares each element. I have for instance `freeze-compare-text` for a plain `diff -u` output, `freeze-compare-kdiff3` to start kdiff3 comparision on each file where there are some changes (with some intelligence to avoid false positives where the 0 element on a new branch is identical with the starting version etc). And I also have a `freeze-compare-diffstat` (basically piping the output to diffstat).

If you just are interested in finding changes between to labels as a one time operation, you can run

```
ct find -avobs –nvisible -version "lbtype(label1)" -print | sort > label1.versions
ct find -avobs –nvisible -version "lbtype(label2)" -print | sort > label2.versions
comm -3 label1.versions label2.versions
```

which will list all elements which do not have identical versions in label1 and label2.