# How to find list of files created and modified in a UCM stream?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool, clearcase-ucm

Whenever developer tries to debug the code they wanted to know list of files created and modified from particular day . I use

cleartool find command with created_since , but it finds only the files which are created not modified.

How to find both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cleartool find command can give you what you want, provided you look for *versions* created since a date, not element (file or directory).

See "[Additional examples of the cleartool find command](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425)":

```
cleartool find <vobtag> -version "{created_since(target-data-time)}" -print
```

Since you are in UCM, you can limit that search to a specific branch name (corresponding to a specific Stream)

```
cleartool find <vobtag> -version "{brtype(BRANCH) && created_since(target-data-time)}" -print
```

Add the user in this request:

```
cleartool find <vobtag> -version "{created_by(user2) && brtype(BRANCH) && created_since(target-data-time)}" -print
```

And you should get what you need for a developer for a given Stream and date.

Comment: Hi VonC, I was trying to execute the command. "cleartool find "M:\ViewName\VobName" -version "{brtype(\main\Integrationstream) && created_since(03-Jan:8:30)}" -print" but no results were shown . but i know that in Jan 3 we did modified many files. Am i missing any thing?

Comment: @Samselvaprabu: try to debug by simplifying the request: `brtype(Integrationstream)` instead of `/main/Integrationstream`. Or use just the `created_since` (without the `-branch`), just to check if at least that works.

Answer (score 0):

Below is example of finding all files changed after 27-Aug-2014

cleartool find . -version "{created_since(27-Aug-2014)}" -print

Answer (score 0):

I followed what  [brainimus](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2462407/3081553) had to say [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462407/find-changes-between-labels)
IBM Clear Case-> Administration -> Report builder.
In the Tree view Under **\Reports** Select **Elements**, and then choose the appropriate option.