# How to get the list of the checkin files between two clearcase ucm lables in unix

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

In clearcase UCM how to get the list of the checkin files between two baselines in linux ?

I am using the shell script but it's getting strucked while running the below command ?

How to redirect the out put to a text or word file ?

cleartool diffbl -act -ver label1 label1 >> data.txt

Answer (score 1):

Note: if your baselines are full, you could use a find query which might redirect in a text file better through the `-print` option.
See "[Find changes between labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462407/find-changes-between-labels/2464604#2464604)".

Otherwise, the technote "[Additional examples of the cleartool find command](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425)" mentions:

#### REDIRECT OUTPUT TO A FILE:

> When running a cleartool find command the text can run off the screen, but you can redirect the output to a text file. To capture the data to a file for viewing, printing or use by a script (or other program) the output can be redirected as follows:
>
> To get the STDOUT information add " `> file_name.txt`" to the end of the command string:

```
cleartool find . -all -print > c:\out.txt
```

> To get both `STDOUT` and `STDERR` information add " `> file_name.txt 2>&1`" to the end of the command string:

```
    Windows    -- cleartool find . -all -print > c:\out.txt 2>&1
    UNIX/Linux -- cleartool find . -all -print >& /tmp/out.txt
```