# How to display recent changes and logs for current view spec in clearcase?

Tags: clearcase

newbie for clearcase.

Since clearcase's config is rather different from other concept in git, I may mean logs for
any files with specified version/branch path.

Like I want to show log for all element match:

```
element * .../specified-lable-or-branch/
```

Comment: Just added the find queries, as requested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to be aware of the [differences between ClearCase and Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645008/what-are-the-basic-clearcase-concepts-every-developer-should-know/645771#645771), ClearCase being file-centric (no notion of repository-wide revision or commit)

You can display logs for any visible file by typing:

```
cleartool lshistory /myView/myVob/path/to/myFile
```

See [`lshistory` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lshistory.htm). (and also [How do I understand about ClearCase event records in the VOB database](http://www.samecs.com/how_do_i/ClearCase_VOBs/ClearCase%20VOBs%20how%20do%20I.htm#_Toc245769698))

> The lshistory command lists event records in reverse chronological order, describing operations that have affected a `VOB`'s data.
>
> - **File system data history**.
>   Lists events concerning elements, branches, versions, and VOB links.
>   This includes records for creation and deletion of objects, and records for attaching and removal of annotations: version labels, attributes, and hyperlinks.

Another kind of logs is the **[`lsvtree`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsvtree.htm)** (history of versions):

> The `lsvtree` command lists part or all of the version tree of one or more elements.
> By default, the listing includes all branches of an element's version tree except for obsolete branches.

[alt text http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/_persistent/tree.PNG?file=74-3724&v=1&c=true](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/_persistent/tree.PNG?file=74-3724&v=1&c=true)

---

The OP adds:

> How can I display all history for elements match a pattern like has new version under a branch?

You can combine almost any commands with a [find query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311623/find-files-in-clearcase).

Windows syntax:

```
cleartool find . -name "apattern" -exec "cleartool lshistory \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""
cleartool find . -version "{created_since(target-data-time)}" -exec "cleartool lshistory \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""
```

Unix syntax:

```
cleartool find . -name "apattern" -exec 'cleartool lshistory "$CLEARCASE_PN"'
cleartool find . -version "{created_since(target-data-time)}" -exec 'cleartool lshistory "$CLEARCASE_PN"'
```

For the " like has new version under a branch?" specifically:

```
cleartool find . -version "brtype(mybranch)" -exec ...
```

should do it (any element which has no version created for that branch will not be listed).

Comment: How can I display all history for elements match a pattern like has new version under a branch?