# listing files checked in during last 2 days

Tags: clearcase

In clearcase I want to list the files /file versions checked in during the last 2 days. Can anyone help me with the command or script for the same.

Answer (score 3):

You will find [plenty of `cleartool find` examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311623/find-files-in-clearcase/1311665#1311665), including:

"[find  all file versions created since a certain date](http://www.samecs.com/commands/cleartool%20commands/find/find.htm#_Toc193967956)"

> List all the files versions below the current directory created since a certain date,

```
cleartool find . -type f -version "created_since(01-Mar)" –print
```

> Note: Add the –follow options if you want to follow any symbolic links that are present.

See the [query_language man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/query_language.htm) for the date format.

Comment: Just to clarify on this one VonC - you're saying that although the age in days parameter is available in the output format - you can't directly query against it - instead you have to reply on a date. (ie A query like "created_since(today - 2)" is not available.)

Comment: @hawkeye yes, the date.time parameter is `date.time | date | time |now` and doesn't support operation relative to it (like `today - 2`)