# Find branches with elements merged to main between a date range

Tags: clearcase

I'm looking for a ClearCase query that will find all the branches that have been merged to main (for a certain VOB) between a given date range.

Alternatively, I could be satisfied with finding all the elements changed on main between a date range.

I was looking at the Report Builder GUI tool, but could not find a report that met my criteria.  I assume I need to use some sort of "ct find" command, but this is not my area of experise.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic query for finding versions or elements created between two dates is:

```
cleartool find . -version 'created_since(10-Jan) && !created_since(11-Jan)' -print
```

(More links and details in "[listing files checked in during last 2 days](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6371054/6309)")

You can couple that with a [`cleartool descr`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm) and [`fmt_ccase`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm) (like `%[hlink:filter]p` and `%Sn`), in order to check if that version has a merge hyperlink associated to it.

- `%[hlink:filter]p` would give you hyperlink(s) associated to the version (if there is/are ones)
- `%Sn` would give you "branch-pathname/version-number", allowing you to extract the branch associated with that version.