# Determine if a label is used

Tags: clearcase

I can list the available labels on a VOB, but what I'd really like to know is if it's possible to determine if the label has been used (but not locked).  Testing each label is very intensive; is there an easier solution?

Answer (score 0):

You at least can test the "lock" part with a simple:

```
cleartool lslock lbtype:mylabel@\myvob
```

For the "has been used" part, as I mention in "[How to search files by label](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2221254/6309)", a [`cleartool find`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1311665/6309) can help, but is (as you noticed) costly:

```
> cleartool find -all -element '{lbtype_sub(REL1)}' -print
```

If you know that those labels *had* to be set at least on a specific folder (like, for instance, the root folder of the vob), you could limit your search to check if one version of that specific folder has the label: that would be much quicker.